# Regex: Selecting Text within Templated Syntax

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to obtain the `value` part of this syntax:

```
[name:value]
```

I got as far as:

```
\[name:(\w*)]
```

Which matches the entire thing. Does anyone know the changes I would need to make to select only value? (Bearing in mind that syntax will also be surrounded by other text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Match.Result` method is what you want. See [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.result.aspx) and [documentation on Regex substitution patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

Use `Regex.Match(input, pattern).Result("$1")` to get what you want.

To give a complete example, here is the unit test I used to confirm that this solution would work:

```
[Test]
public void TestRegexMatchResult() {
    var input = "Other text [name:value] and other text";
    var pattern = @"\[name:(\w+)\]";

    Assert.AreEqual("value", Regex.Match(input, pattern).Result("$1"));
}
```

The test passes.

You can also go through a string and extract multiple occurrences of the pattern:

```
[Test]
public void TestRegexMatchesResult() {
    var input = "Some [name:value] pairs [name:something] here.";
    var pattern = @"\[name:(\w+)\]";

    var results = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).OfType<Match>()
        .Select(match => match.Result("$1"));

    Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Count());

    Assert.AreEqual("value", results.ElementAt(0));
    Assert.AreEqual("something", results.ElementAt(1));
}
```

Finally, if you need to abstract this to something other than "name", you can do this:

```
[Test]
public void TestMatchingNameAndValue() {
    var input = "[key:value] [another_key:some_other_value]";
    var pattern = @"\[(\w+):(\w+)\]";

    var results = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).OfType<Match>()
        .Select(match => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            match.Result("$1"),
            match.Result("$2")));

    Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Count());

    Assert.AreEqual("key", results.ElementAt(0).Key);
    Assert.AreEqual("value", results.ElementAt(0).Value);
    Assert.AreEqual("another_key", results.ElementAt(1).Key);
    Assert.AreEqual("some_other_value", results.ElementAt(1).Value);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank You. Could you explain how the $1 thing works?

Comment: $number just gets the corresponding parenthesized group. You have one set of parenthesis, so one group, and that group is number 1, so `$1` gets that group.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

The regex will always match the entire string, but you can access the matching portion with the **[Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)** member collection:

```
public static void Main()
{
   string pattern = @"(\d{3})-(\d{3}-\d{4})";
   string input = "212-555-6666 906-932-1111 415-222-3333 425-888-9999";
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

   foreach (Match match in matches)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Area Code:        {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
      Console.WriteLine("Telephone number: {0}", match.Groups[2].Value);
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

(this example is taken from the page referenced)

Comment: How does it know the difference between groups?

Comment: Good, but Match.Result is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to only match `value`.

Search for `(?<=\[name:)\w+(?=])`

This means: Match one or more alphanumeric characters, if and only if they are preceded by `[name` and followed by `]`. Note that it's not necessary to escape the `]`.

Comment: This is not necessary as .NET will give you access to parenthesized parts of regexes.

Comment: I know that it's not necessary, but it's what the OP wanted - an alternative solution by Michael Bray was already there, and now there is another one by yourself.